# ValueError: There aren't any elements to reflect in axis 0 of `array` when calling librosa.feature.melspectrogram

Tags: python, mel, librosa

I'm trying to extract the mel spectrograms for different audio files and for some of them I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 25, in script_process_file
>       bounds, events, features, RMS = process_file(_file,version=None,output=True,reading=True,cython=False,corr_FIR=None,features_list = features_list_all, tree_function =Tree_4_0_0,data=data, amplify=None)
>
> File "pcm_algorithm/process_file.py", line 111, in process_file
>       mel_spec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(sound,n_fft=256,hop_length=128,n_mels=n_mels).T
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/feature/spectral.py", line 1388, in melspectrogram
>       power=power)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py", line 1179, in _spectrogram
>       S = np.abs(stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length))**power
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/librosa/core/spectrum.py", line 160, in stft
>       y = np.pad(y, int(n_fft // 2), mode=pad_mode)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/arraypad.py", line 1420, in pad
>       " in axis {} of `array`".format(axis))
>   ValueError: There aren't any elements to reflect in axis 0 of `array`

I use **256 fft points** with **128 frames overlap** and **40 mel_bands**. Any advice would be really helpful.

Here is the exact line of code that gives me an error:

```py
n_mels = **40**

mel_spec =  librosa.feature.melspectrogram(sound,n_fft=**256**,hop_length=**128**,n_mels=n_mels).T
```

Comment: I could imagine passing `center=False` to the STFT might solve the issue. However, are you certain that your audio files are long enough, i.e. not empty or close to empty?

Comment: Hi hendrik, all my files are 5 minute recordings with sample rate 22050Hz in mono. So, I don't really think that center=False would make any difference.

Comment: The problem is that when I load up the sound with librosa.load function everything works perfect, but when I use the scipy.io.wavfile library I get this error:

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py:273: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/io/wavfile.py:273: WavFileWarning: Chunk (non-data) not understood, skipping it.
  WavFileWarning)

(sorry for my bad editing but actually it's my first time posting in stackoverflow)

Comment: Sounds like you're having corrupted wave files.